# Android: Widget not updating when it should

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget layout of two ImageViews and a button. Whenever I tap the button, the two image views should get some random images in my resource files. My problem is for the first few clicks, the image views are properly getting new images, but after that, even though I am setting images using the `setImageViewBitmap()`, but to no use.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After few clicks whats happening? is it crashing?

Comment: the app won't crash. lets say I have some 100 images. First 5 clicks, the two imageviews are updated with some random images from the 100. but afterwards, no matter how many times I click my button, the images won't change. I debugged it, I am getting two new images, and calling setImageViewBitmap() to set them, however, the old images won't change.

Comment: Please post the code snippet u r using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is due to the exception " FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION". 
Please look into this discussion.
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-developers/KKEyW6XdDvg/discussion

Thx@
rahul.